# Unable to Login Into SQLExpress from Windows Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I have two Windows 2016 Servers, each has SQL Express installed. Both servers have 
- port 1433 TCP and 1434 UDP enabled (inbound and outbound)
- Remote Connection is enabled
- From desktops both servers are individually accessible using server name like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433.

Therefore assuming that firewall is handled adequately in both the servers

However using SQL management studio on Server 1, I am unable to login to Server 2. And Vice versa.

The following is the error -

Cannot connect to 1xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

Any idea what is the problem?

This is what I have already tried-

1) I tried to open all ports (inbound and outbound) for given IPs. Problem still persists.

2) possible solutions given in the following post -  [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Is TCP/IP enabled on both servers? Can you see the connection attempt in the SQL Server logs?

Comment: What credentials are you using to connect? If it's an SQL server account (and not a Windows account) check that Mixed Mode authentication is enabled on both SQL servers.

Comment: TCP/IP is enabled on both the servers. Tested the same by connecting desktops

Comment: Both the servers have only SQL authentication

Comment: Inbound as well as outbound Firewall rule is configured for ports 1433 (TCP) and 1434 (UDP)